# expected assignment or function call: no-unused-expressions ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, jsx

```
class Game extends Component 
{
  constructor() 
  {
    super()
    this.state = {
      speed: 0
    }
    //firebaseInit()
  }
  render()
  {
    return 
    (
      <div>
        <h1>The Score is {this.state.speed};</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Game;
```

I am new to React and for this code its giving this error

```
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
```

Dont understand where getting wrong, please help

Comment: The error message normally comes with where it's complaining, e.g. which file, which line.

Comment: @zcui93 it shows error in this file and in the return line, can you please help

Comment: Which line? please provide details

Comment: @Think-Twice it shows in Line 18 which is the line which have return

Comment: post question properly with code.

Comment: @ThakurKarthik what else should i specify, i provided the code , error and the error line?

Comment: return problem .. you may forget one

Answer (score 180, accepted):

This happens because you put bracket of `return` on the next line. That might be a common mistake if you write js without semicolons and use a style where you put opened braces on the next line.

Interpreter thinks that you return undefined and doesn't check your next line. That's the `return` operator thing

Comment: The JavaScript parser will automatically add a semicolon when, during the parsing of the source code, it finds these particular situations:
1. when the next line starts with code that breaks the current one (code can spawn on multiple lines). 
2. when the next line starts with a }, closing the current block
3. when the end of the source code file is reached
4. when there is a return statement on its own line
5. when there is a break statement on its own line
6. when there is a throw statement on its own line
7. when there is a continue statement on its own line.

Comment: I got the same error. But I did not use return() there. how can i resolve that?

Answer (score 110):

In my case I had **curly braces** where it should have been **parentheses**.

```js
const Button = () => {
    <button>Hello world</button>
}
```

Where it should have been:

```js
const Button = () => (
    <button>Hello world</button>
)
```

The reason for this, as explained [in the MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_syntax) is that an arrow function wrapped by `()` will return the value it wraps, so if I wanted to use curly braces I had to add the `return` keyword, like so:

```js
const Button = () => {
    return <button>Hello world</button>
}
```

Comment: This was the issue for me

Comment: One whole year after I started to learn web development, I never once realised that arrow functions occasionally needed `return`.. I need to go look over my old code and maybe I'll see why certain things weren't working. Especially in react..

Thanks for actually providing this answer!

Comment: This solutions worked and I understand now why it was giving me error.

Answer (score 42):

For me the error occured when using map. And I didn't use the return Statement inside the map.

```
{cart.map((cart_products,index) => {
    <span>{cart_products.id}</span>; 
})};
```

Above code produced error.

```
{cart.map((cart_products,index) => {
    return (<span>{cart_products.id}</span>); 
})};
```

Simply adding return solved it.

Comment: Same happend to me, it only worked after adding return. But htis is wired!

Comment: it is because map takes a function. 
(cart_products,index) => {
    return (<span>{cart_products.id}</span>); 
}
is actually a declaration for function. So, when we return the returned value will be used.

Comment: But what made me wonder is that the code of the tuto work fin without the return!!!

Comment: Maybe in the tutorial. The code was wrapped around in () bracket. If you wrap it in () it won't be needing return.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using JSX inside a function with braces you need to modify it to parentheses.

Wrong Code

```
return this.props.todos.map((todo) => {
            <h3> {todo.author} </h3>;
        });
```

Correct Code

```
//Change Curly Brace To Paranthesis   change {} to => ()
return this.props.todos.map((todo) => (
            <h3> {todo.author} </h3>;
        ));
```

Comment: It is a good practice if we pass a second parameter i.e, index to the map function

Answer (score 4):

In my case i never put **return** inside a arrow function 
so my code is follow

```
`<ProductConsumer>
   {(myvariable)=>{
      return  <h1>{myvariable}</h1>
   }}
</ProductConsumer> `
```

Comment: But when I put a return in an arrow function it works fine. How?

Comment: If we put curly bracket in an arrow function we need always need to return.

Comment: yes thats a function so it should return some value

Answer (score 3):

In my case I used commas instead of semicolons in constructor.

Example with errors:

```
class foo(bar1, bar2, bar3){
    this.bar1=bar1,
    this.bar2=bar2,
    this.bar3=bar3,

}
```

instead I should have used semicolons like underneath:

```
class foo(bar1, bar2, bar3){
    this.bar1=bar1;
    this.bar2=bar2;
    this.bar3=bar3;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error happened because the new line after the `return` statement.

Error : Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

```
return
(
    <ul>
        {
            props.numbers.map(number => <li key={number.toString()}>number</li>)
        }
    </ul>
);
```

Working OK. No Error

```
return (
    <ul>
        {
            props.numbers.map(number => <li key={number.toString()}>number</li>)
        }
    </ul>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error, with the below code.

```
    return this.state.employees.map((employee) => {
      <option value={employee.id}>
        {employee.name}
      </option>
    });
```

Above issue got resolved, when I changed braces to parentheses, as indicated in the below modified code snippet.

```
      return this.state.employees.map((employee) => (
          <option value={employee.id}>
            {employee.name}
          </option>
        ));
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case it is happened due to braces of function if you use JSX then you need to change braces to parentheses:

```
const [countries] = useState(["USA", "UK", "BD"])
```

I tried this but not work, don't know why

```
 {countries.map((country) => {
        <MenuItem value={country}>{country}</MenuItem>
  })}
```

But when I change Curly Braces to parentheses and Its working fine for me

```
  {countries.map((country) => ( //Changes is here instead of {
        <MenuItem value={country}>{country}</MenuItem>
  ))} //and here instead of }
```

Hopefully it will help you too...

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution: Move the start of opening bracket...

[image: Move the start of the bracket]

When you use the return keyword, just make sure that the START of the bracket is ON THE SAME LINE as the `return` keyword. If you don't do this, you will get a bug.

Answer (score 2):

### In my case I replaced `,` with `;`

Change from this

```
<Button
    onClick={() => {
        function1(), function2();
    }}>
    Click
</Button>
```

to this

```
<Button
    onClick={() => {
        function1();
        function2();
    }}>
    Click
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';

class Counter extends React.Component{
    state = {
        count: 0,
    };

    formatCount() {
        const {count} = this.state;
        // use a return statement here, it is a importent,
        return count === 0 ? 'Zero' : count;
    }
    render() {
        return(
          <React.Fragment>
              <span>{this.formatCount()}</span>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Increment</button>
          </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have got this error, because used a call inside of the condition without a semicolon:

```
  private async _setActive(active: boolean) {
    if (this.isActive === active) {
      return;
    }
    this.isActive = active;

    this.isActive ? this._start() : this._stop();
  }
```

I changed it, and the error has gone:

```
  private async _setActive(active: boolean) {
    if (this.isActive === active) {
      return;
    }
    this.isActive = active;

    if (this.isActive) {
      await this._start();
    } else {
      this._stop();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error - "***Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions***" comes when we use curly braces i.e {} to return an object literal expression. In such case we can fix it with 2 options

1. Use the parentheses i.e ()
2. Use return statement with curly braces i.e {}

Example :

```
const items = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"];
console.log(articles.map(item => { `this is ${item}` })); // wrong
console.log(items.map(item => (`this is ${item}`))); // Option1
console.log(items.map(item => { return `this is ${item}` })); // Option2
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone having a problem like i had. I was using the parenthesis with the return statement on the same line at which i had written the rest of the code. Also, i used map function and props so i got so many brackets. In this case, if you're new to React you can avoid the brackets around the props, because now everyone prefers to use the arrow functions. And in the map function you can also avoid the brackets around your function callback.

```
props.sample.map(function callback => (
   ));
```

like so. In above code sample you can see there is only opening parenthesis at the left of the function callback.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
 return 
 (
  <div>
    <h1>The Score is {this.state.speed};</h1>
  </div>
 )
```

Use Below Code

```
 return(
   <div>
     <h1>The Score is {this.state.speed};</h1>
   </div>
  )
```

Basically use brace **"("** in the same line of return like **"return("**. It will fix this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the error on the setState line:

```
increment(){
  this.setState(state => {
    count: state.count + 1
  });
}
```

I changed it to this, now it works

```
increment(){
  this.setState(state => {
    const count = state.count + 1

    return {
      count
    };
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add my solution in case anyone else is experiencing this error. In my case it didn't have anything to do with brackets, an arrow function or a missing return statement. I had a check like this

```
if (this.myProperty) {
    this.myProperty == null
}
```

I had to remove this then the error went away. It was difficult to figure this out because the error message was not at all descriptive.