# How to Bind "this" with setState callback

Tags: reactjs

How can I bind "this" with setState callback. Does react allows it?

```
this.state = {
    selectedId: null,
}

//On click of some list item as

<ListGroup.Item 
  action href="" 
  key={id}
  onClick={()=>
    this.setState({selectedId: id.ID}), () => console.log(this.state.selectedID)
  }
>
  LIST ITEM
</ListGroup.Item>)
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, Can you please elaborate on what your question is?

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: You have to provide a more complete example and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer I want to bind this with seState callback. As currently, console.log give me this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined" which most likely refers to talk about binding this

Comment: Please see my answer.

Comment: Hi Meena, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind `onClick` and not `setState` so that when bound `onClick` calls `setState`, it can 'supply' this in order to make the call. In React class components handlers like `onClick` are bound in constructor:

```js
class BindingExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedId: null }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState( prevState => (...prevState, { selectedId: id.ID }),
                   () => console.log(this.state.selectedID)
                 );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
         Click me
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

If `onClick` was implemented as a fat arrow function

```js
handleClick = () => {
   this.setState( prevState => (...prevState, { selectedId: id.ID }),
                   () => console.log(this.state.selectedID)
                );
}
```

then there wouldn't be any need to bind it because fat arrow functions always capture this.
As a sidenote, class components are currently out of fashion in React.

Comment: why fat arrows always capture this ?

Comment: @AfrazAhmad Fat arrows always capture `this` by design. In other words it's a feature of ES6.

Comment: No, its because fat arrow functions are moved inside constructor during compile time. its like you are defining a function inside constructor which has 'this' in its parent scope.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad "No, its because fat are moved inside constructor during compile time"  Fat arrow functions capture `this` even when there are no classes and no constructors around. In which case `this` is captured from execution context. It's by design and this is a fundamental feature. What happens at compilation time is a technicality chosen by authors of the compiler to implement the design requirement.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad: You are mixing up two different things: Public class fields (which are syntactic sugar for assigning properties to `this` in the constructor) and arrow functions. Public class fields are often used with arrow functions to achieve the effect you mentioned, but only because arrow functions resolve `this` this way, not the other way round.

Comment: @winwiz1 I still face this "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions" which I guess is more about the syntax and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined"

Comment: And yes I have class Component

Comment: @Meana When getting several errors, a good approach is to focus on the first one and forget the rest for a moment. Regarding "Expected an assignment ...", yes it's syntax, maybe related to brackets and curly braces. Hard to tell without seeing your code, can it be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013437/expected-assignment-or-function-call-no-unused-expressions-reactjs)

Comment: @winwiz1 Ok it works...I figured out my mistake. At some point in my code while looping through my data array, I was using regular function instead of callback function. So in case, the reference for "this" was being lost. May be , next time should post complete code. Thanks alot anyways!!

Comment: fat arrow functions always capture this. THIS statement is **wrong**. Actually what happens is that arrow function doesn't capture anything, and it skipped this. That's why the outside this is leaked in.

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented `callback` of `setState` in a wrong way here,

```
onClick={()=>
  this.setState({selectedId: id.ID}), () => console.log(this.state.selectedID)
}
```

Your setState is ended here itself,

```
this.setState({selectedId: id.ID})   //This is complete setState
```

You if want to add `callback` to `setState`, you need to write it inside of `setState` as,

```
onClick={()=>
  this.setState({
     selectedId: id.ID
  }, () => console.log(this.state.selectedId)   //This is callback
  ) //end of setState
} //end of onClick
```

**Note:** You are printing `this.state.selectedID`, but in state your have `selectedId`.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-northcutt-uqpih?fontsize=14)

Comment: Tried  and Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: @Meana, can you post complete component code, or can you provide codepen / codesandbox?

Comment: @Meana, Check out the Demo link.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind `this` when you run an inline callback arrow function.

The issue with your code is that you have 2 functions

```
onClick={()=> this.setState({selectedId: id.ID})
//// this line is wrong
, () =>
////
console.log(this.state.selectedID)}
```

Change your onClick code to this:

```
onClick = {() => {
        this.setState({selectedId: id.ID}); 
        console.log(this.state.selectedID)
}}
```

Also this seems wrong.

```
this.state = {
    selectedId: null,
}
```

Change it to this:

```
state = {
    selectedId: null,
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No it does not work. Error: " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined " I thinks my code is fine for setState call back..just need to bind "this" with it

Comment: Is there a line number of where the error occurs? If yes what's on that line?

Comment: It is with console.log, as "this" returns undefined and can not read state value.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, Also is your component a class component or a functional component?

Comment: @ShmiliBreuer There is no `this`, no `setState` and no `this.setState` in functional components

Comment: Correct, that's why I asked to make sure this isn't the cause for the issue.