# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and this is my first application.I'm having this error... I saw some possible duplicates in stackoverflow.but those answers not solve this problem

> > ./src/components/app/App.js
> >       Line 7:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

### Code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return 
    (
      <div className="container">
        <h2>react.......</h2>
      </div>
    );

  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: do you have any online working code snippet?

Comment: no.i don't have it..

Comment: try to put the bracket at the same line `return ( ....` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013437/expected-assignment-or-function-call-no-unused-expressions-reactjs