# I want to fetch my orders data from the service file, but there is an error that im not successful to solve

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

the error in the console is :
ERROR in [eslint]
src\services\orders.js
Line 9:3:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

app.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Table } from './components/Table';
import {ordersService} from './services/ordersService'


function App() {
  
  const [orders , setOrders] = useState(null)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
    const ordersData = await ordersService.query();
      console.log(ordersData);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Table orders={ orders } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

services\ordersService.js

```
export const ordersService = {
  query
}


function query(sortBy) {
  return Promise.resolve(gOrders)
}


const gOrders = [{
    "order_ID": 2790846857303,
    "name": "#38777",
    "total_refunded": 0,
    "created_at": "2020-11-23 23:27:52",
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013437/expected-assignment-or-function-call-no-unused-expressions-reactjs

Comment: You don't show the content of the file mentioned in error message "src\services\orders.js" or named it differently.  Make sure you have provided full example containing the line mentioned in the error message "Line 9:3"

Comment: the content of the file wich the error comes is in ordersService.js

Comment: Are you sure that you have copied all related code? Try to reproduce the issue here https://t.ly/7ekN

Comment: I fixed the problem, at first I changed the name of the file and then I changed it back, I had to restart the application, thank you