# Call multiple functions in onClick ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The issue lies within the **`<Button>`** component, specifically in its **`onClick`** event handler, which needs to perform two tasks:

1. Navigate back to the previously visited route using the **`useNavigate`** hook.
2. Change the name of the button from "GoBack" to "Home" by passing appropriate props.

[`CodeSandBox`](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-cartwright-3stjj3)

In codeSandBox go to the src/Home.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = (props) => {
    const history = useNavigate();
    return (<div style={{ height: '100vh' }} className={`text-${props.mode} bg-${props.dmode}`}><h1 >{props.Name}</h1>
        <Button variant="contained" color="success" onClick={() => { () => (history(-1)); props.toggleHomeBTN }}>{props.home}</Button>
    </div>)
}

export default Home;
```

**ERROR**

[image]

Already referred  StackOverFlow Questions

- [How to go back to previous route in react-router-dom v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948671/how-to-go-back-to-previous-route-in-react-router-dom-v6)
- [Call multiple functions onClick ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069238/call-multiple-functions-onclick-reactjs)
- [expected assignment or function call: no-unused-expressions ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013437/expected-assignment-or-function-call-no-unused-expressions-reactjs)
- But None of the above worked for me!!!!!!

How can I implement a functionality where, upon clicking a button on the root route ("/") page, the user is redirected to the previously visited page, and the button's text changes from "Go Back" to "Home" using props?

**CodeSandBox**

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-cartwright-3stjj3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the `props.toggleHomeBTN` function like this:

```
onClick={() => {
  history(-1);
  props.toggleHomeBTN?.();
}}
```

The `?.` operator will handle the invoked function being `undefined` or `null`. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

It can be potentially omitted and in that case the code would look like this:

```
onClick={() => {
  history(-1);
  props.toggleHomeBTN();
}}
```